# embedding a slideshow photo gallery with Picasa that autorepeats?

Tags: html, flash, image-gallery, picasa

how can I modify the embedded photo gallery slideshow from Google's Picasa to auto repeat the pictures, i.e. play them over and over again?  This is the code Picasa gives me for embedding in a website:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://picasaweb.google.com/s/c/bin/slideshow.swf" width="400" height="267" flashvars="host=picasaweb.google.com&hl=en_US&feat=flashalbum&RGB=0x000000&feed=http%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Fdata%2Ffeed%2Fapi%2Fuser%2F102341124641778821128%2Falbumid%2F5469290618448219537%3Falt%3Drss%26kind%3Dphoto%26hl%3Den_US" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
```

Related to this, are there free tools that take as input a Picasa username or a set of photos and automatically create a thumbnailed gallery, which is embeddable using Flash in any website?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in the embed tag I believe you can add `loop="true"`

so

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" loop="true" src="http://picasaweb.google.com/s/c/bin/slideshow.swf" width="400" height="267" flashvars="host=picasaweb.google.com&hl=en_US&feat=flashalbum&RGB=0x000000&feed=http%3A%2F%2Fpicasaweb.google.com%2Fdata%2Ffeed%2Fapi%2Fuser%2F102341124641778821128%2Falbumid%2F5469290618448219537%3Falt%3Drss%26kind%3Dphoto%26hl%3Den_US" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
```